# Is there a suitable conjunction which fits the meaning of “as a continuation of”?

Tags: single-word-requests, conjunctions, discourse-markers

I want to use it in my thesis. Like *secondarily*, but I don't want to use that one or similar words, as these specify an order.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Could you give an example, please? It's hard to know what exactly you're looking for without context.

Comment: So, I have explained one figure in the text, and the next figure will give a meaning differently from the first one but it has dependence to the first figure. And to connect these two sentences I'd like to have a conjunction and that is I am looking for.

Comment: @StoneyB yup I' ve found it. The requested conjunction was "subsequently".

Comment: If that's what you're looking for, cool. But *subsequently* just means *later* or *afterwards*, not *as a continuation*; and it's an ordinary adverb, not a conjunction.

Comment: You don't wanna say *wanna* in your thesis.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

1. subsequently
2. consequently
3. afterwards
4. succeeding
5. thereafter

Secondarily also means that what you about to say is of less importance than what was said afore. You could use:

1. Additionally
2. In addition
3. As a result,
4. less importantly
5. albeit

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want to pursue an idea at greater length, by adding supplemental evidence or argument to what you've already said, consider using *furthermore* or *moreover*. The word *further* and the phrase *in addition* (cited by Steward Godwin Jornsen in his answer) also convey the idea of continuation, but they chiefly indicate "something in addition to the previous sentence," whereas *furthermore* and *moreover* indicate "something reinforcing or amplifying the previous sentence."